# iOS7 NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest failed with POST data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

My problem is adopt the `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest...]` with `POST` method fails on iOS7 failed but succeeds on iOS6 environment.

Other information:

1. in my iOS6 environment can get JSON data from Server like this. (successful)

   ```
   {
       "status": 200,
       "data": [
           {
               "oauth_token": "BVgOa01tg6JvfuXOPoJS8wB26TpvAaDs"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. same code on iOS7 will get this error message. (Failed)

   > error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.)
3. I check the server side PHP code, Found the server can get data from iOS6 POST data, but can't get the POST data from iOS7. (Same code different result, very strange.)

Have anyone can help me or suggestion for me? thanks a lot.

#### My Code is below (Updated to v3, Successful)(Thanks for Rob' Answer)

```
- (void) apiLogin
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"client_id"     : @"1234567",
                         @"response_type" : @"token",
                         @"redirect_uri"  : @"/oauth2-php/server/examples/pdo/",
                         @"state"         : @"test_state",
                         @"scope"         : @"",
                         @"accept"        : @"Yep",
                         @"uid"           : uid,
                         @"pwd"           : withPwd};

    NSData *postDataString = [self dataForHTTPPost:params];

    // Server API 位置
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.tw/xxx.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120];
    [request setURL:url];

    // Solution3:
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postDataString length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postDataString];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        NSLog(@"D1: responseCode: %d", responseCode);
        if (!connectionError && responseCode == 200) {
            // 採用Apple官方方法將 來源轉成JSON Format並交由NSDictionary 接手.
            NSError *localError = nil;
            NSLog(@"data:%@", data);
            NSDictionary *allInDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&localError];
            NSLog(@"Source:%@", allInDic);
            NSLog(@"error:%@", localError);

            // 取出oauth_token資料
            if ([[allInDic objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 200) {

                // 將新取得之 oauth_token 寫入DB
                NSArray * dataArray = [allInDic objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSDictionary *responseData = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString *t = [responseData objectForKey:@"oauth_token"];
                [helper setDbOauthToken:nil :t :TABLE_USER_PROFILES];
                NSLog(@"(API-New)oauth_token:%@", t);
            } else
            {
              NSLog(@"connectionError=%@", connectionError);
              NSLog(@"responseCode=%d", responseCode);
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (NSData *)dataForHTTPPost:(NSDictionary*) parms
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *key in parms) {
        id obj = [parms objectForKey:key];
        NSString *valueString;

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
          valueString = obj;
        else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
          valueString = [(NSNumber *)obj stringValue];
        else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
          valueString = [(NSURL *)obj absoluteString];
        else
          valueString = [obj description];

        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, valueString]];
    }
    NSString *postString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
    NSLog(@"New2a HTTPPost Data:%@", postString);

    return [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {

    [self apiLogin];
}
```

#### Below Code is Debugging output on iOS6

```
New2a HTTPPost Data:response_type=token&uid=xxx&accept=Yep&scope=&client_id=1234567&state=test_state&redirect_uri=/oauth2-php/server/examples/pdo/&pwd=xxx
D1: responseCode: 200
data:<7b227374 61747573 223a3230 302c2264 61746122 3a5b7b22 6f617574 685f746f 6b656e22 3a224870 47366546 4b304a37 38434343 54306352 506e4d77 62544d5c 2f455631 32793422 7d5d7d>
Source:{
    data =     (
                {
            "oauth_token" = "HpG6eFK0J78CCCT0cRPnMwbTM/EV12y4";
        }
    );
    status = 200;
}
error:(null)
(API-New)oauth_token:HpG6eFK0J78CCCT0cRPnMwbTM/EV12y4
```

#### Below Code is Debugging output on iOS7

```
New2a HTTPPost Data:response_type=token&uid=&accept=Yep&scope=&client_id=1234567&state=test_state&redirect_uri=/oauth2-php/server/examples/pdo/&pwd=
D1: responseCode: 200
data:<>
Source:(null)
error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x8a28d90 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}
connectionError=(null)
responseCode=200
```

#### Thanks for Rob big helps, My Problems was solved. The root course is below code. In IOS6 I can get uid/withPwd default value when no input on "idField.txt" field. But In iOS7 this code can't get the default value with (uid/withPwd). Thanks for Rob my problem was solved.

```
NSString *uid = idField.text;
NSString *withPwd = pwdField.text;

// For testing Account ID
if (!uid||!withPwd) {
    uid=@"xxx@gmail.com";
    withPwd=@"xxxx";
}
NSLog(@"uid:%@ , pwd:%@", uid, withPwd);
```

#### Updated the problem code to this is fine to work on iOS6 & iOS7

```
// For testing Account ID
if ([uid isEqualToString:@""] || [withPwd isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    uid=@"xxx@gmail.com";
    withPwd=@"xxxx";
}
```

Comment: Did you *actually* get an error from `NSJSONSerialization`? You MUST confirm this by checking the return value of `NSJSONSerialization`s class method. Otherwise, _localError_ may contain junk - even you initialized it with `nil`.

Comment: I am currently debugging an identical problem. It looks like the post data isn't being encoded properly in iOS 7.0.2.

Comment: @bshirley I just tested the above code in 7.0.2 and it works without incident. If you have any of the reserved characters in your `postData`, you have to encode with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, but other than that, this works fine in iOS 7.0.2.

Comment: Dear Rob, Please see my updated question & Debugging output on iOS6 & iOS7, If you have other suggestion please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logging `data`, but you probably want to look at a string representation of that. Look at the resulting string and see what is in that response from the server. That way, if your server failed and returned some non-JSON error message, you can see what the string was.

Likewise, you might want to log the `connectionError` if it's not `nil`. That's not the case here (otherwise, you wouldn't have gotten to your current `NSLog`, but it's probably worthwhile to look at that if it's not `nil`). Thus:

```
if (!connectionError && responseCode == 200) {
    // 採用Apple官方方法將 來源轉成JSON Format並交由NSDictionary 接手.
    if (data)
        NSLog(@"data string: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    else
        NSLog(@"data is nil");

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *allInDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"Source:%@", allInDic);
    NSLog(@"error:%@", parseError);

    // 取出oauth_token資料
    if ([allInDic[@"status"] integerValue] == 200) {

        // 將新取得之 oauth_token 寫入DB
        NSArray * dataArray = allInDic[@"data"];
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = dataArray[0];

        NSString *t = responseDictionary[@"oauth_token"];
        [helper setDbOauthToken:nil :t :TABLE_USER_PROFILES];
        NSLog(@"(API-New)oauth_token:%@", t);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connectionError=%@", connectionError);
    NSLog(@"responseCode=%d", responseCode);
}
```

I suspect that once you look at the string representation of your `data`, the problem may become self-evident.

---

By the way, it's unlikely to be the issue, but make sure you're properly encoding the strings you're adding to your `postData`. For example, if your password contains an ampersand, a plus sign, a space, or some other reserved character (as described in section 2.2 of [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)), your current code will not work. You may want to apply [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes) to the value you add to your `postData`, for example you can use a `NSString` category like so:

```
@implementation NSString (URLPostEncode)

- (NSString *)stringForHTTPPost
{
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=+$,",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}

@end
```

I personally combine that with the following `NSDictionary` category:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (URLPostEncode)

- (NSData *)dataForHTTPPost
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *valueString;

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            valueString = obj;
        else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            valueString = [(NSNumber *)obj stringValue];
        else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
            valueString = [(NSURL *)obj absoluteString];
        else
            valueString = [obj description];

        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [valueString stringForHTTPPost]]];
    }];

    NSString *postString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

    return [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

Having those two categories, I can then do something like:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"client_id"     : client_id,
                         @"response_type" : response_type,
                         @"redirect_uri"  : redirect_uri,
                         @"state"         : state,
                         @"scope"         : scope,
                         @"accept"        : accept,
                         @"uid"           : uid,
                         @"withPwd"       : withPwd};

NSData *postData = [params dataForHTTPPost];
```

Comment: Failed Solution1 1)Add NSLog(ConnectionError/ResponseCode) 2) Adobt stringForHTTPPost Encoding. 
Below is Solution1 result:

Comment: Dear Rob, thanks for your helps, above is adobt your solution 1 debugging logs. Other I will try your new solution2. wait moment response.

Comment: @PotatoHwang It's hard to read those error codes in the comments. The key question is when you look at `data`, (a) is it non-`nil`; and (b) if so, when you convert it to a `NSString`, what does it contain. Perhaps you can update your question with what the `NSString` representation of `data` was. (If `data` is not JSON, there's no point in worrying about the error you get from `NSJSONSerialization` ... you have to figure out why `data` is not JSON.)

Comment: updated the error code is same below. error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x8a26b80 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: Yes I neeed to figure out why data is not JSON. Other I check the server side PHP code, Found the server can get data from iOS6 POST data, but can't get the POST data from iOS7. THis is root course, but I don't know why Server can't get iOS7 POST data.

Comment: @PotatoHwang I spent a little time comparing headers and other parameters of the request received by the server for iOS6 and iOS7 request, and other than an inconsequential difference in the `User-Agent` (the `CFNetwork` version number), I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the cache policy and see if that helps

```
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
```

try using

```
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

Comment: It's same that got the below error code on iOS7: error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x8a26b80 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}